# Enclosing classes in WCF

Tags: .net, wcf

Well Im fairly new in WCF services and I don't even know if its possible, but here is my problem.

I have a web site with multiple WCF services, all of the services get the data from the same database. Im using LinqToSql to get the data model. For example, I have a ProjectsService with a PROJECT class and also a have an AccountsService with a ACCOUNT class, the problem is that if someone reference the ProjectService, he is able to use ACCOUNT class. It is possible to restrict the access to some clases that doesn't belong to the required service?

Comment: What is your client side technology?  DotNet or non-DotNet (or both)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this, you'll need to break up your entities so that they live in different assemblies, that way your services can reference only the assembly that contains the entity that it cares about.  Otherwise, there's no way to segment the code so that ProjectService can only talk to the Project entity if it's referencing the DataModel.dll assembly.

If you want to break your entities up into separate assemblies, you will need to create separate data models for each entity, with each of these models living in a separate class project.  You should be able to have no problem creating multiple data models against the same database, each referencing a different table or view in that database.